# Show that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}\text{Aut}(G_i)\cong \text{Aut}\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}G_i\Big)$ (intuition on smaller $n$)

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, intuition, group-isomorphism

> Let $G_1,...,G_n$ be groups of finite order such that theirs orders $|G_i|$ are pairwise coprime. Show that $\xi:$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\text{Aut}(G_i)\cong \text{Aut}\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}G_i\Big)$.
> Here I won't really consider the case for $n$. I would like to consider $n=2$ and write my intuition on this statement. I saw that there are some posts for this statement (for $n=2$), but I didn't really find a clear explication. If someone could comment, give a feedback on it or help to solve the problem, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance

So let's consider the case for $n=2$. Let $G_1,G_2$ be groups of finite order such that theirs orders $|G_1|, |G_2|$ are coprime. What I think is that to show that ${\rm Aut}(G_1\times G_2)\cong{\rm Aut}(G_1)\times {\rm Aut}(G_2)$, I can show that there is injection in both directions (and then conclude by Cantor Schroeder Bernstein). In my previous **[post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130358/show-that-prod-i-1n-textautg-i-to-textaut-big-prod-i-1ng-i-b)** I showed that there is an injection $\xi:{\rm Aut}(G_1)\times{\rm Aut}(G_2)\to{\rm Aut}(G_1\times G_2)$.

My problem, now, is how to define properly the injection $\eta:{\rm Aut}(G_1\times G_2)\to {\rm Aut}(G_1)\times{\rm Aut}(G_2)$.

What I think, is that I can define $\eta$ as:

$\eta(\phi)=(\phi_1,\phi_2)$ where $\phi_1 \in \text{Aut}(G_1\times \{e\})$ and $\phi_2\in \text{Aut}(\{e\}\times G_2)$.

But, once I send $\phi$ to ${\rm Aut}(G_1)\times{\rm Aut}(G_2)$ by $\eta$, I don't really see which elements to apply to the 2-tuple $(\phi_1,\phi_2) \in {\rm Aut}(G_1)\times{\rm Aut}(G_2)$.

For example if we take $\phi \in{\rm Aut}(G)$, then we can take $g\in G$ and send it by $\phi$ to $G$. But how does it work in ${\rm Aut}(G_1)\times{\rm Aut}(G_2)$?

Could I define it as the following?

$(\phi_1,\phi_2)(g_1,g_2)=(\phi_1(g_1),\phi_2(g_2))$.

Then, if yes, I don't understand where to apply the coprimeness of $|G_1|$ and $|G_2|$... With this definition of $(\phi_1,\phi_2)$, we can only notice that $\phi(g_1,g_2)=\phi_1(g_1)\cdot \phi_2(g_2)$.

Sorry in advance for kinda "vague" explication and thanks for help!

Comment: The usual way to say that any two are coprime in (American?) English is “pairwise coprime”. “two-by-two coprime” sounds like a literal translation, perhaps form the Spanish version of the phrase? (coprimos dos a dos)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin From French x) Thank you for correction, I edit it now.

Comment: The case $n=2$ is all you need - the general case follows by an easy induction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Of course!

Comment: Without the pairwise relatively prime, the problem is that there are *more* automorphisms. For example, when $G_1=G_2,$ the map $(g_1,g_2)\mapsto (g_2,g_1)$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Yes, that is your way of embedding $Aut(G_1)\times Aut(G_2)$ into $Aut(G_1\times G_2).$ It is not hard to see that this is a homomorphism, and one-to-one. The hard part is proving it is onto.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews But if I construct Injective morphisms in both directions, can’t I conclude directly that there is a bijective morphism by Cantor Schroeder Bernstein?

Comment: No, Schroeder Bernstein doesn't say the two functions are bijections, only that a bijection exists, and there is no reason to think the bijection resulting would be a homomorphism.

Comment: Much weaker, however, is that all the groups are finite, so if there are injections both ways, then the injections are isomorphisms. But I think it is easier to prove this homomorphism is onto.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I thinked about it and I juste have a question: if we can find the injection in both directions, doesn’t it follow that $|\text{Aut}(G_1 \times G_2)|=|\text{Aut}(G_1) \times \text{Aut}(G_2)|$? Then as my application is injective and the order of both groups is equal, then it is isomorphic? I think that what you told me in the previous comment. Isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, because the groups are finite, There are infinite examples of group injections $H_1\to H_2$ and $H_2\to H_1$ where $H_1,H_2$ are not isomorphic. For example, $$H_1=\oplus_1^\infty C_4, H_2=C_2\oplus H_1.$$ where $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Alright, thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find a homomorphism
$$
\eta:  \text{Aut}(G_1\times G_2)\to \text{Aut}(G_1)\times \text{Aut}(G_2).
$$

The best guess is $\eta(\phi)=(\phi|_{G_1}, \phi|_{G_2})$: but that will only work if $\phi|_{G_i}(G_i)=G_i$. It is here that the coprimeness comes into play. It is easy to prove the following lemma; and with it we are sure that $\phi|_{G_i}(G_i)=G_i$. It's easy to check the injectivity, easy to check that $\eta$ is a homomorphism, and easy to check that $\eta$ is the inverse of your map $\text{Aut}(G_1)\times \text{Aut}(G_2)\to \text{Aut}(G_1\times G_2)$.

**Lemma** The only elements of order dividing $|G_i|$ in $G_1\times G_2$ lie in $G_i$.